# C++11 rvalue reference in pipe operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

I trying my hand at rvalue reference with some generic implementation of a virtual pipeline class.

```
template<class I, class O>
class Pipeline
{
    vector<I> _inputs;
    virtual O Execute(void)
    { return foobar( _inputs ) }
};
```

I would like to implement the operator | (pipe) that combines multiple pipelines together:
EDIT: change code with pointers so that it matches my next code example

```
// Pipeline* p1, p2, and p3 already exist
Pipeline* p0 = p1 | p2 | p3;
// is equivalent to
p2->_inputs.push_back(p3->execute());
p1->_inputs.push_back(p2->execute());
p0->_inputs.push_back(p1->execute());
```

I thought rvalue reference was very appropriate for this :

```
template<class I,class O>
Pipeline<I,O>&& operator | (Pipeline<K,O>* a, Pipeline<I,K>* b)
{
    Pipeline* p0 = a;
    Pipeline* p1 = b;

    p0->_inputs.pushback(p1->execute); //inputs is vector<I*> instead of vector<I>
    return std::move(p0);
}
```

Note, that I would prefer pass by adress rather than value because typename I and O could potentially be big objects and Pipeline could have such big private attributes in it's inner working.

However the above code clearly has a lot of memory management issues:
1/ std::move(p0) means p1 is never freed/deleted
2/ if I work directly on a and b instead of p0 p1, I loose the original pointers?

Can someone help me and tell me how to use an rvalue ref for the pipe operator please?

EDIT: According to @Alexey Guseynov my example is not adapted for rvalue ref. rather than functional code (Minimal Complete Verifiable example) I am looking for an explanation as to why && is not valid here and also when are we are supposed to use them: What is the philosophy behind them and what exactly do they bring to the table.
Thank you in advance

Comment: `Pipeline p0,p1,p2,p3;` is not valid code. I don't know how anyone can help you without a [mcve].

Comment: Im pretty sure `p0 = p1 | p2 | p3;` would do `p1 -> p2 -> p3` and then store the output of `p3` in `p0`.

Comment: Just to clarify - this isn't the pipe operator in C++, it's the OR operator ... you may prefer to use the stream operator

Comment: @Sahu I do not have a minimal working example, this is exactly what I am struggling to do. Sorry

Comment: @NathanOliver the order of operation is a good point. I am less concerned with it at the moment though, I can fix it when I have a proper working example.

Comment: @UKMonkey Semantics: the pipe is the name of the symbol |. OR is the name of the OPERATOR that is represented by the pipe. I could change it to stream operator but honestly it does not matter, does it?

Comment: Agreed - Semantics - but then so is not calling functions "sort" rather than "dave"... good luck to the next engineer working on it.

Comment: I understand. I might change it change it in my code. Thank you for bringing it up

Answer (score 0):

Argument type in declaration must match types of arguments you use. So if you use objects themselves:

```
call.Pipeline p0,p1,p2,p3;
p0 = p1 | p2 | p3;
```

Then operator | must take objects. In your case it must take `const Pipeline&`. Note, that semantically `operator |` does not modify it's operands, so you should not use `Pipeline&` despite that it allowed.

Rvalue reference is not a good type to return: they are just not designed to be used here. You will return a reference to a temporary object which does not exist any more. You should return a value here.

So in the code you've shown there is no place for pointers, so there are no problems with memory management.

Comment: Then it seems I do not understand rvalues. I read multiple things about them but I seem to miss the point. Would you be able to tell me why they were invented in the first place? What do they bring to the table. When is it a good idea to use them (std::move seemed appropriate in my case but you say it is not). Tutorials I googled all use generic examples but don't explain the general context and reason why of &&

Comment: Anyone Please?
I would like to understand when are staple situations that absolutely require rvalue reference as opposed to regular values.